# Form-control datepicker in c# webforms jquery 1.8.20

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, datepicker

I have this code in my aspx page:

```
<div class="form-group">
            <asp:Label ID="lbl_Make" runat="server" Text="Make:"></asp:Label>
            <asp:TextBox ID="tb_Make" CssClass="form-control datepicker-input" data-mask="9999-99-99" runat="server" placeholder="Enter Make"></asp:TextBox>
            </div>
```

how come this is the result of the datepicker:

[image]

need help on this any other suggestions?

i already have these on my `bundleconfig.cs` :

```
 "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.datepicker.css",
 "~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js"));
 "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.20.js"));
 "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.datepicker.css",
  "~/Content/assets/third/datepicker/css/datepicker.css",
  "~/Content/assets/third/datepicker/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js",
```

Comment: you probably need to add some css file to your project

Comment: Yep, looks like you miss the css file

Comment: any hunch on missing file? im pretty sure I included all bootstrap and jquery files on my bundle